# Troubles in using gRPC python server with ruby client

Tags: python, ruby, grpc

gRPC does not seem to work in such config. Minimal not working example:

Protobuf spec:

```
// a.proto
syntax = "proto3";
message M { string s = 1; }
service A {  rpc Serve(M) returns (M); }
```

Generating stub

```
#!/bin/sh
#codegen.sh
protoc -I . --ruby_out=. --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=`which grpc_ruby_plugin` a.proto
protoc -I . --python_out=. --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=`which grpc_python_plugin` a.proto
```

Server (follows helloworld example)

```
  #!/usr/bin/python
  #python_server.py
  import a_pb2 
  import time
  from grpc.beta import implementations
  class AServer(a_pb2.BetaAServicer):
    def Serve(self, request, context):
      return a_pb2.M(s = request.s)
  server = a_pb2.beta_create_A_server(AServer())
  server.add_insecure_port("localhost:666123")
  server.start()
```

Python client (works fine)

```
  #!/usr/bin/python
  #python_client.py
  from grpc.beta import implementations
  import a_pb2 
  channel = implementations.insecure_channel('localhost', 666123)
  stub = a_pb2.beta_create_A_stub(channel)
  req = a_pb2.M(s = "test".encode('utf-8'))
  response = stub.Serve(req, 10)
  print "got " + response.s
```

Ruby client (appears to ignore server)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#ruby_client.rb
$LOAD_PATH.unshift '.'
require 'grpc'
require 'a_services'
stub = A::Stub.new('localhost:666123', :this_channel_is_insecure)
req = M.new(s: "test")
response = stub.serve(req)
puts("got #{response}")
```

Python client outputs "got test" as intended. Ruby client dies with exception

```
in `check_status': 12:Method "Serve" of service ".A" not implemented! (GRPC::BadStatus)
```

Versions: `gem list` outputs`google-protobuf (3.0.0.alpha.3)` and `grpc (0.12.0)`
`pip list` outputs `protobuf (3.0.0a3)` and `grpcio (0.12.0b0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service ".A" in the error message most likely means this is a bug when using an empty package name in your .proto. I filed [an issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/4984) for it.

A workaround is easy though; just specify 'package' in your proto file:

```
// a.proto
syntax = "proto3";
package your.package.name;
message M { string s = 1; }
service A {  rpc Serve(M) returns (M); }
```

Package names are a good thing to specify, in general, to prevent name collisions.